# cppcheck format string on member functions of C++

Tags: c++, cppcheck

aa.h

```
#ifndef __US_LOG_FILEA_H_
#define __US_LOG_FILEA_H_

namespace AA{
class A{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    static A& Ins(){
        static A obj;
        return obj;
    }
    void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format ...);  // ok
    void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format, ...);  // error
};

} // namespace AA
extern AA::A g_A;

#endif // __US_LOG_FILEA_H_
```

formatstr.cpp

```
void test()
{

g_A.do_p("global func", 2, "%s\n", str);

}
```

a.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<def>
  <function name="AA::A::do_p">
    <noreturn>false</noreturn>
    <leak-ignore/>
    <formatstr type="printf"/>
    <arg nr="3">
      <formatstr/>
      <not-uninit/>
    </arg>
  </function>
</def>
```

cppcheck --enbale-style --library=a.cfg formatstr.cpp

if void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format ...);  cppcheck output:
warning: %s in format string (no. 1) requires 'char *' bu
t the argument type is 'std::string'. [invalidPrintfArgType_s]
g_A.do_p("global func", 2, "%s\n", str);

but  do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format,...);  cppcheck output nothing

**WHY?**

The Cppcheck's version is 1.89.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AA::A::Ins().do_p("member func", 2, "%s\n", str);  CppCheck also not work

Comment: where is the definition of `do_p` ? what is `str` in `test()` ?

Comment: `#define __US_LOG_FILEA_H_` that's a reserved identifier. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: 3Q! I have tried.  I'm using #pragma once.void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char* Format, ...)  is ok.  void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format, ...)  do not work.

Answer (score 1):

> WHY?
>
> ```
> void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format ...);  // ok
> ```

Presumably because cppcheck doesn't recognise `const char *Format ...` as a printf format and variadic arguments unless they are separated by comma, so you didn't get the error.

> ```
> void do_p(const char *cat, int level, const char *Format, ...);  // error
> ```

You configured cppcheck to check bad format / argument pairing, so this is where you should expect an error.

Answer (score 1):

1st, modify the Cpp member function code to C-style function
2nd, remove overload funcions